# Выполнить действия по порядку с интервалом во времени

Tags: android

Нужно выполнить действия по порядку, с интервалом во времени. Шаблон:

```
-перерыв 5 сек
Действие 1
-перерыв 5 сек
Действие 2
-перерыв 5 сек
Действие 3
```

Не пойму, делать по очереди:

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        //Действие 1

                    }
                }, 5000);

                final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
                handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        //Действие 2

                    }
                }, 5000);

                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        //Действие 3

                    }
                }, 5000);
```

Или друг в друге:

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    //Действие 1

                           final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
            handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    //Действие 2

                 final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
            handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    //Действие 3

                }
            }, 5000);

                }
            }, 5000);

                }
            }, 5000);
```

А если по очереди, то нужно ли временной интервал прибавлять к предыдущему, например 5, 10, 15 сек. Как будет правильнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Правильный вариант первый, только с прибавлением предыдущего времени. 5000, 10000 и 15000 соответственно. Выходит отсчёт начинается от начала самого события, а я думал идёт по очереди - хандлер 1 завершился, хандлер 2 пошёл и тд.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html Прочитайте про Executor. Можно организовывать очереди выполнения, а также получать Future и отменять их когда надо.